# Laravel Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::toSql does not exist. error

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to search all records from database and then filter these records but when i want to seee the query with

```php
dd($posts->toSql());
```

it gives me the error

```php
"Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::toSql does not exist."
```

it gives me one more error

```php
"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist."
```

```php
$posts = Post::all();

        if( !is_null($brand) )
            $posts = $posts->where('brand', $brand);

        if( !is_null($car_type) )
            $posts = $posts->where('car_type', $car_type);

        if( !is_null($color) ){
            $posts = $posts->where('exterior_color', $color);
        }
        $posts = $posts->whereBetween('year',[$from_year,$to_year]);   
        $posts = $posts->whereBetween('milage',[$min_milage,$max_milage]);
        $posts = $posts->whereBetween('price',[$min_price,$max_price]);

        $posts = $posts->paginate(4);

        dd($posts->toSql());
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Laravel : 5

You can not `->paginate()` or `->toSql()` after `Post::all() / Post::get()`

### What you need to do :

Use below :

```php
$posts = Post::query();

if( !is_null($brand) )
    $posts = $posts->where('brand', $brand);

$posts = $posts->whereBetween('year',[$from_year,$to_year]);   
$posts = $posts->whereBetween('milage',[$min_milage,$max_milage]);
$posts = $posts->whereBetween('price',[$min_price,$max_price]);

// $posts = $posts->paginate(4);

dd($posts->toSql());
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, replace `Post::all()` with `Post::query()`. You are fetching all the results before you start filtering.

The `paginate()` method will perform the query and load the results into a `Collection`, which means that you're calling `toSql()` on a collection instead of a query builder instance.

Therefore, you should either call `toSql()` before you call `paginate()`, or if you want to see the pagination constraints you could do the following before you run the query / in a service provider.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

// ...

DB::listen(function ($query) {
    var_dump($query->sql);
});
```